# How to optimize mapping over several tables

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I'm trying to optimize my code. The solution described below works fine, but I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do it. Do you have any recommendations?

I have one table with business contracts and some characteristic attributes:

```
table_contracts
contract_number       attribute_1        attribute_2        attribute_3
123                         a                  e                   t
456                         a                  f                   s
789                         b                  g                   s
```

And a second table that maps each contract into a specific group. These groups have different priorities (higher number => higher priority). If the attribute column is empty it means that it is not required (=> m3 is the catch all mapping)

```
table_mappings
map_number    priority    attribute_1        attribute_2        attribute_3
m1                5           a                  e                   t
m2                4           a
m3                3
```

As a result I need the the contract_number and the corresponding map_number with the highest priority.

This is how I did it, it works but does anyone knows how to optimize that?

```
with 
first_selection as 
  (
    select
    table_contracts.contract_number
    ,table_mappings.priority
    ,row_number() over(partition by table_contracts.contract_number order by table_mappings.priority desc)
    from table_contracts
    left join table_mappings
        on (table_contracts.attribute_1 = table_mappings.attribute_1 or table_mappings.attribute_1 is null)
        and (table_contracts.attribute_2 = table_mappings.attribute_2 or table_mappings.attribute_2 is null)
        and (table_contracts.attribute_3 = table_mappings.attribute_3 or table_mappings.attribute_3 is null)
   ),
second_selection as
   (
    select
    table_contracts.contract_number
    ,table_mappings.priority
    ,table_mappings.map_number
    from table_contracts
    left join table_mappings
        on (table_contracts.attribute_1 = table_mappings.attribute_1 or table_mappings.attribute_1 is null)
        and (table_contracts.attribute_2 = table_mappings.attribute_2 or table_mappings.attribute_2 is null)
        and (table_contracts.attribute_3 = table_mappings.attribute_3 or table_mappings.attribute_3 is null)
   )
select
first_selection.contract_number 
,second_selection.map_number
from first_selection
join second_selection 
    on first_selection.contract_number = second_selection.contract_number and first_selection.priority = second_selection.priority 
where first_selection.rn = 1
```

The output of this code would be:

```
Results
contract_number       map_number
123                       m1
456                       m2
789                       m3
```

Comment: Please add sample output for the above input for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @vCillusion: Post above is edited!

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one of the selections :

```
with prioritized as(
   select c.contract_number, c.attribute_1, c.attribute_2, c.attribute_3, m.map_number
         ,row_number() over(
            partition by c.contract_number
                order by m.priority desc
         ) as rn
     from table_contracts     c 
     left join table_mappings m on(
          (c.attribute_1 = m.attribute_1 or m.attribute_1 is null)
      and (c.attribute_2 = m.attribute_2 or m.attribute_2 is null)
      and (c.attribute_3 = m.attribute_3 or m.attribute_3 is null)       
     )
)
select * 
  from prioritized
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below logic using CTE version similar to yours. Hope it helps!

[Demo](http://rextester.com/EZAUZ70092)

```
 WITH contracts AS
        (SELECT 123 AS contract_number, 'a' AS attribute_1, 'e' AS attribute_2, 't' AS attribute_3 FROM   dual 
         UNION 
         SELECT 456, 'a', 'f', 's' FROM   dual 
         UNION SELECT 789, 'b', 'g', 's' FROM   dual
        ), 
 mappings AS
        (SELECT 'm1' AS map_number, 5  AS priority, 'a'  AS attribute_1, 'e'  AS attribute_2, 't'  AS attribute_3 FROM   dual 
         UNION 
         SELECT 'm2', 4, 'a', NULL, NULL FROM   dual 
         UNION 
         SELECT 'm3', 3, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM   dual
        ), 
 prioritymap AS
        (SELECT contract_number, 
                map_number, 
                Rank() over(PARTITION BY contracts.contract_number ORDER BY mappings.priority DESC) AS rank 
          FROM contracts 
               JOIN mappings 
                  ON ( contracts.attribute_1 = mappings.attribute_1 OR mappings.attribute_1 IS NULL ) 
                     AND ( contracts.attribute_2 = mappings.attribute_2 OR mappings.attribute_2 IS NULL ) 
                     AND ( contracts.attribute_3 = mappings.attribute_3 OR mappings.attribute_3 IS NULL )
        )
SELECT contract_number, map_number 
FROM   prioritymap 
WHERE  prioritymap.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join the tables on the condition given (an attribute is null in the maping table or must match the attribute in the contracts table). Then aggregate per contract number to get the best map_number.

```
select
  c.contract_number,
  max(m.map_number) keep (dense_rank last order by m.priority) as map_number
from table_contracts c
join table_mappings m
  on  (m.attribute_1 is null or m.attribute_1 = c.attribute_1)
  and (m.attribute_2 is null or m.attribute_2 = c.attribute_2)
  and (m.attribute_3 is null or m.attribute_3 = c.attribute_3)
group by c.contract_number
order by c.contract_number;
```

Anyway, you are doing this for all contracts and a mapping may match on any combination of attributes, so this will lead to full table scans. The only way I can see to get this quicker is parallel excecution. Maybe the DBMS is set to do this automatically, otherwise you can use a hint:

```
select /*+parallel(4)*/
...
```